# Use multiple filters in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm desperately looking for a way to make multiple filters on my board. Currently I'm using the filter() function to filter some elements of my array. I would need to display the elements of several arrays with the same key but I can't do it.

My controller:

```
$arrays = $arrays->filter(function ($item) use ($five, $four, $three, $two){
                return data_get($item, 'note') == $five;
            });
```

I would need to display the arrays containing the note keys with `$five` `$four` `$three` and `$two`. Would it be possible to do multiple `data_get` in the same function?

Comment: Does something like this would work `return in_array(data_get($item, 'note'), [$five, $four, $three, $two])`  ?

Comment: No, it doesn't works

Comment: So you are trying to filter your collection or are you trying to group them by your parameters?

Comment: Yes I trying to group them with my parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to filter by an array of `$values` then you may want to consider doing something like this instead:

```
$values = collect([$five, $four, $three, $two]);

$arrays->filter(function ($value) use ($values) {
   return $values->has($value);
});
```

If you are checking the value of a key -> value pair, the use the `contains()` method
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-contains

If you are checking for the key of a key -> value pair, then use the `has()` method
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-has

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is not necessarily a `filter()` but a `groupBy()` function.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

If you are trying to group by the value of a property then all you may need to do is this

```
$arrays->groupBy('note');
```

If you are trying to group by something more complex then you can use a callback (similar to your filter)

```
$arrays->groupBy(function ($item) use ($five, $four, $three, $two) {
    // return the value you wish to group by
    switch ($item->note) {
        case $five:
           return 'five';
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that came out wrong. I would like to see in my collection only arrays with the values of `$five`, `$four`, `$three` and `$two` to stand out. Not the others.

Comment: @RootMeIH Can you give us an example of input / output of the array(s) you have and how you would like to have ?